# Node.js xml2js stop encoding html entities

Tags: xml, node.js

I'm new to node.js and has been tasked to manipulate a XML file, I used xml2js converter for easy manipulation but after getting the result I can see that URL containing **&** are getting converted to **amp;**

```
var xml = builder.buildObject('xml containing & html entities');
response.write(xml);
```

Any one has any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: It doesn't need to,you can not use **&** directly in xml,the *&* will be converted to the predefined entity *&amp;* automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this-

var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: 23};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by enabling the cdata option in the builder constructor.

var builder = new xml2js.Builder({cdata:true})